# How do you delete an element in a list while in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a loop to check that my 'new users' are not already in my 'current users' list. If they are not, they get added to the current user list and then removed from the new user list.

I seem to struggle to delete the element in the new user list after the check has happened. I don't get the expected result when I add the lines in line 32 or 33.

My code below:

```
# Task at hand: Checking Usernames
# create a program that simulates
# how websites ensure that everyone has a unique username.


# HELP NEEDED - Current issue:
# Can't seem to be able to remove the new user once he has been added to the 
# current_user list. 


current_users = ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin']
new_users = ['vali', 'donal', 'aoife', 'robert' , 'gerry']

if current_users:
    if new_users:

        for new_user in new_users:
            if new_user.lower() in current_users:
                print(f'This user already exists. Please chose a new user:  {new_user.title()}')

            else:

            # I also tried replacing "else:" with "if new_user.lower() not 
            # in current_users:" but no luck.

                current_users.append(new_user.lower())
                print(f"Perfect, you have been added to the database: {new_user.title()}")

                # I could not manage to remove the new_user from the list
                # straight from here. 
                # I tried the following 2 'solutions':
                # del new_users[0]
                # new_users.remove(new_user.lower())

    else:
        print("You need new users to check against.")

else:
    print("You need some existing users to check against.")


# Check status of lists: 
print(f"\nCurrent users: {current_users}")
print(f"New users: {new_users}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of `new_users` to iterate over, and then remove from the original list:

```
current_users = ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin']
new_users = ['vali', 'donal', 'aoife', 'robert' , 'gerry']

if current_users:
    if new_users:
        for new_user in new_users.copy():
            if new_user.lower() in current_users:
                print(f'This user already exists. Please chose a new user:  {new_user.title()}')
            else:
                current_users.append(new_user.lower())
                print(f"Perfect, you have been added to the database: {new_user.title()}")
                new_users.remove(new_user)
    else:
        print("You need new users to check against.")
else:
    print("You need some existing users to check against.")

# Check status of lists:
print(f"\nCurrent users: {current_users}")
print(f"New users: {new_users}")
```

This avoids the issue of modifying the list you're iterating over.

Output:

```
Current users: ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin', 'vali', 'donal', 'aoife', 'gerry']
New users: ['robert']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the new user list while you are iterating over it, you can do it by iterating over its indices backwards. In this way if you delete the current item, the indices you still need to traverse won't change.

```py
current_users = ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin']
new_users = ['vali', 'donal', 'aoife', 'robert' , 'gerry']

if current_users:
    if new_users:

        for i in range(len(new_users)-1, -1, -1):  # backward sequence of indices
            if new_users[i].lower() in current_users:
                print(f'This user already exists. Please chose a new user:  {new_users[i].title()}')
            else:
                current_users.append(new_users[i].lower())
                print(f"Perfect, you have been added to the database: {new_users[i].title()}")
                del new_users[i]

    else:
        print("You need new users to check against.")
else:
    print("You need some existing users to check against.")

# Check status of lists: 
print(f"\nCurrent users: {current_users}")
print(f"New users: {new_users}")
```

Output:

```py
Perfect, you have been added to the database: Gerry
This user already exists. Please chose a new user:  Robert
Perfect, you have been added to the database: Aoife
Perfect, you have been added to the database: Donal
Perfect, you have been added to the database: Vali

Current users: ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin', 'gerry', 'aoife', 'donal', 'vali']
New users: ['robert']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_users = ['paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'maria', 'admin']
new_users = ['vali', 'donald', 'aoife', 'robert' , 'gerry']

for current,new in zip(current_users, new_users):
    if new.lower() in current:
        print('This user already exists. Please chose a new user')
        new_users.remove(new)
    else:
        current_users.append(new.lower())
        print("Perfect, you have been added to the database")
        new_users.remove(new)


# Check status of lists: 
print(f"\nCurrent users: {current_users}")
print(f"New users: {new_users}")
```

Comment: This is not going to work as intended, for a number of reasons. For example, your `if` condition only checks the existing username of the same index as the current user.

Comment: @Arne I do not get you the zip construct seperates both lists and uses the initiator variables as pointers, kindly clarify what you mean, thanks

Comment: `zip()` does not separate the lists. On the contrary, it intertwines them. Quoting from the official documentation: "Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables." https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip